# Powerapps Xrm.WebApi in a stand alone Web Resource

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamics-crm-webapi, powerapps-modeldriven

I have a stand alone web resource linked from the site menu in a Model Driven App.  It does multiple api calls using `parent.Xrm.WebApi` and currently works fine.

According to Microsoft deprecation notice, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/important-changes-coming, `parent.Xrm` will be going away and no longer work for standalone Web Resource.   `Xrm.WebApi` without referencing the parent throws an error "Xrm" is not defined.

Can anyone help with a supported way to access `Xrm.Utility` and `Xrm.WebApi` from a standalone web resource?

Comment: Hi DanWa, welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 1):

Latest [documentation update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/getglobalcontext-clientglobalcontext.js.aspx):

> The ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx page is deprecated and scheduled to be unavailable after April 1, 2022. Alternative methods to access global context information will be available by December, 2021.

---

On this particular piece, so far nothing documented as workaround or alternate solution from Microsoft. I created a [github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerapps-docs/issues/1756) for the assistance and it is still open.

Between, I came to know about one of the MS employee [unofficial side project](https://github.com/chnichol/mock-xrm/) and code sample from [this blog](https://carldesouza.com/use-mock-xrm-to-upgrade-removed-clientglobalcontext-dynamics-365). That is also about to be confirmed as supported.

> A lot of organizations use ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx in HTML web
> resources, and this means you will want to upgrade those HTML web
> resources that utilize the ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx library as soon
> as possible.
>
> If you are embedding HTML web resources in Dynamics 365 / Power Apps
> forms, you may want to look at using getContentWindow.
>
> If you have stand-alone HTML web resources, or if you are embedding in
> forms and would like a neat way to swap out
> ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx with a new library, Microsoft employee
> Christopher Nichols has built a solution that may be of interest to
> you.
>
> Christopher has a nice unofficial side project going on called
> mock-xrm that, as you can imagine, mocks xrm. This means we can call
> our Xrm functionality from within web resources that instead of the
> legacy aspx page.

All we have to do is just download the `Xrm.min.js` file as web resource and this has to be referred in our HTML web resource to consume `Xrm` the same way as earlier.

We can keep a close eye on this library and github issue for further updates and concrete communication.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.  This is a great solution for now, and hopefully MS will have better guidance on a supported solution in the future.

Comment: @DanWa pls find the update, support removal date is postponed & there’s a new date and alternative solution date also promised :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to come back and update the post.  That is a most welcome delay.

Comment: @DanWa my pleasure, pls upvote/accept if this answer helped you..